# Why am I not able to create a new node for my struct in C ? ( using Netbeans )

Tags: c, pointers, netbeans, struct, stack

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
 int info;
 node *link;
 };

 node *top = NULL;
 void push();
 void pop();
 void display();

 main()
 {
  int choice;

  while(1)
  {
  printf("Enter your choice:\n1.Push\n2.Pop\n3.Display\n4.Exit\n");
  scanf("%d",&choice);

  switch(choice)
  {
   case 1:
    push();
    break;
   case 2:
    pop();
    break;
   case 3:
    display();
    break;
   case 4:
    exit(1);
    break;
   default:
    printf("Wrong choice");
   }
//   getch();
  }
 }

 void push()
 {
  node *tmp;
  int pushed_item;
  tmp = new node;
  printf("Enter the value to be pushed in the stack:");
  scanf("%d",&pushed_item);
  tmp->info=pushed_item;
  tmp->link=top;
  top=tmp;
 }

 void pop()
 {
 node *tmp;
 if(top == NULL)
  printf("Stack is empty");
 else
  {
   tmp=top;
   printf("Popped item is %d",tmp->info);
   top=top->link;
   delete tmp;
  }
 }

 void display()
 {
 node *ptr;
 ptr = top;

 if(top==NULL)
 printf("Stack is empty");
 else
 {
 while(ptr != NULL)
  {
   printf("%d\n",ptr->info);
   ptr=ptr->link;
  }
 }
 }
```

I get an error whenever I try to create a new node, such as in

```
 node *tmp;
 tmp = new node;
```

Error is at the second line. It works properly in other IDEs like TurboC++, but in Netbeans it gives me the error : " Identifier whose declaration cannot be found. "

Answer (score 5):

There is no `new` (and `delete`) operator in C. You have to use standard function `malloc` (and `free`) declared un header `<stdlib.h>` instead.

Take into account that this structure definition

```
struct node{
 int info;
 node *link;
 };
```

is invalid in C. You have to use tag `struct` in the definition of link. For example

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *link;
};
```

And function main in C and C++ shall have return type `int`.

It seems that TurboC++ compiled your code as a C++ code.